# Change the "row index counter" at pgfplotstable

Tags: counters, pgfplotstable

Is it possible to change the "row index counter" (locally) at pgfplotstable. Maybe as a style?

As a test example: 
I skipped some rows in the second table. If the "row index counter" starts at 2 (or 3?) in the second table, the row with the number 4 should be highlighted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\pgfplotstableread[]{
No.    A     B
0    x     x
1    x     x
2    x     x
3    x     x
4    x     x
5    x     x
6    x     x
7    x     x
8    x     x
9    x     x
}{\mytable}

\begin{document}
\section{The row with Number 4 should be highlighted in both Tables}
\subsection{Row 4 should be highlighted}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, 
every row no 4/.style={   before row=\rowcolor{yellow}},
skip rows between index={5}{6}
]{\mytable}

\subsection{Row 4 should be highlighted too!}
How too change the "row index counter"?

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, 
every row no 4/.style={   before row=\rowcolor{yellow}},% <---- !
skip rows between index={0}{3}
]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```